# Unable to Sync already Existed Plans in Djstripe

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

When I add a new Product using the Stripe Dashboard I can see the webhook call come through, I can see the event "product.created" added in Django however whenever i made change in already existed plans and product, djstripe is unable to update the already existed row of that plan. I'm already running the command

```
    python manage.py djstripe_sync_plans_from_stripe
```

after each time i update any plan/product or create any new plan/product

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update the plans automatically by using plan.updated webhook for e.g.

```
@webhooks.handler("plan.updated")
def update_plans_hook(event):
   upadte code..
```

djstripe webhook documentation for webhook configuration.
https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/webhooks.html